# subset of a metric space and continuous functions

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let $$S = \{ x \in M \, | \, f(x) = a \}$$ be closed and $g$ a continuous function from $M$ to $\mathbb{R}$. If we change it to $f(x) \leq a$, then it won't be a line and S would not be closed anymore. Is my reasoning correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What makes you say it's not closed? If $f$ is continuous then
$$S = \{ x \in M : f(x) \le a \} = f^{-1}((-\infty,a])$$
so $S$ is the preimage of a closed set... so what can you say about it?

Comment: OK, then it's definitely closed. T = (−∞,a] is closed in R. By continuity, g−1(T') is open in M, which equals (g−1(T))' so g−1(T) is closed in M.

Comment: @Bob: Yup.${}{}$